# unordered_set using hash of value object's address

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, std

I have a class which needs to have a `std::unordered_set` which holds non-copyable, non-moveable entity objects, and whose hash function hashes the instance's address.  Something like the following:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
    void operator=(const A&) = delete;
    void operator=(A&&) = delete;

    bool operator==(const A& other) { return this == &other; }
};

template<>
struct std::hash<A>
{
    size_t operator()(const A& obj) const
    {
        return std::hash<A*>()(&obj);
    }
};

class B
{
private:
    std::unordered_set<A> entities;
};
```

If `emplace()` is always used instead of `insert()`, is it safe to use `unordered_set` in this way?  Does the standard specify that an implementation can't move node objects after they are constructed?

What about if `A` were moveable?  Is it guaranteed that the hash function will be called on the object owned by the set, or since the standard library prefers to think of everything as value-objects, is it allowed to hash an `insert`ed object before storage is allocated for it?

As a final thought, I know I could get around all this by using `std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr<A>>`, but I'd like to use a custom allocator for the `A` objects, and I don't want to override `new` and `delete` for `A`.

Comment: You don't have to override `new` and `delete`, you can use `std::unique_ptr<A, D>` with a custom deleter `D`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still think you are better off using a `std::list`. Consider:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class A
{
public:
    int i_;
    A(int i) : i_(i) {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
    void operator=(const A&) = delete;
    void operator=(A&&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    std::list< A > l;

    // inserting elements
    auto it1 = l.emplace( l.end(), 1 ); // note: complexity is O(1)
    auto it2 = l.emplace( l.end(), 2 );
    auto it3 = l.emplace( l.end(), 3 );
    auto it4 = l.emplace( l.end(), 4 );

    // deleting an element by iterator
    l.erase( it2 ); // note: complexity is O(1)
    // note: it2 is now invalid

    // accessing element by iterator
    it3->i_ = 42;

    for( const auto& e : l ) {
        std::cout << e.i_ << std::endl;
    }

    // silence compiler warnings
    (void)it1;
    (void)it4;
}
```

In the above, all your use-cases should have an efficient implementation. You can avoid the overhead of calculating the hash and having the hash-map. It's even more efficient as your hash-based approach, for the list both operations are O(1) and much more light-weigth wrt the implementation. And storing the iterator is not much different from storing a pointer to the element directly.

Also, it is guaranteed that this works for non-copyable and non-movable types. See the documentation for [`std::list::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace).

Comment: The only problem is that there is no way to directly convert a pointer to a list element to an iterator, so you'd have to pass around the iterator instead of references/pointers to the actual object.  Theoretically it would be possible to convert a pointer to an iterator if you knew a particular object was in the list, since the iterator is usually just a pointer to the node object (a static offset from a pointer to the value object), but in practice its too dangerous, since if the object *weren't* in the list, it would likely yield an illegal access exception and crash the program.

Comment: @bcrist Which is why you store an iterator if and only if it is in your list, otherwise you pass an `A*` directly (or even better `std::unique_ptr<A>`?). That way there is no real danger to confuse the two, using the static typing to protect you. Anyways, I think you have enough information now to make your own decision. FWIW, I agree on the part you called "too dangerous" :)

Comment: Anyway, you are right that using `unordered_set` for this is a little convoluted and inefficient for this use (though it works if you only use `emplace`.  I decided to spend some more time considering different program structures and ended up not needing this functionality after all.

Comment: I am accepting your answer, even though it doesn't exactly answer the specific questions posed, since it is likely to be the most useful for other people.

Answer (score 2):

Using the address of an object as a hash pretty much guarantees that you won't find the object unless you already hold a pointer to the object other than iteration through the hash. You'll need to come up with a different approach to get a hash from your object. That said, once consructed inside the hash the object's address won't change.

Comment: `emplace()` and `insert()` return an iterator to the new element, so there is no problem finding it.

Comment: @bcrist: why put it into a hash set if you don't want to search for the object? Using a list or a deque seem to be the more obvious and more efficient choices. The use of associative containers is to locate objects quickly. Other containers are better at just storing objects.

Comment: @bcrist ...especially if you store the pointer to it anyways, you don't need to "find" the object, you already know it! (to complete Dietmar's comment)

Comment: Because `B` (in the above example) owns the `A` objects, but needs to be able to destroy any arbitrary `A` object without searching through all the other elements.

Comment: @bcrist: Your described needs are what a `std::list<T>` is for.

Comment: Except removing an item from a list requires an O(n) linear search.

Comment: @bcrist Not if you have the iterator available. I added an answer with some code to show it.

Answer (score 0):

As Dietmar mentions, once constructed, the value's address can't change.  As far as the second part of the question, the standard seems to not only allow, but require implementations to call the hash/equal_to functors on an object passed to `insert()` by reference, rather than requiring the construction of a node first and calling the functions on that object:

> **From 23.2.5 Table 103 — Unordered associative container requirements**
>
> `pair<iterator, bool> a_uniq.insert(t)`
>
> Effects: Inserts `t` if and only if there is no element in the container with key equivalent to the key of `t`.